# I am using htaccess that is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have url like

http://example.com/index.php/allmodels/Samsung-mobiles_80

and i want to convert into

http://example.com/index.php/allmodels?st=Samsung-mobiles_80

I am using following code

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^allmodels/(.*)$ /allmodels?st=$1 [NC,L]
```

but this code is not working.

All the setting is correct I have tested and htaccess is working.

Comment: What exactly isnt working and what folder is the htccess in?

Comment: htaccess in root directory. and url rewrite is not working properly so i got 404 error.

Comment: If i  use ---->  RewriteRule  .* index.php/$1 than code is working

Comment: You are rewriting to **/allmodels** does the url **/allmodels?st=value** work?

Comment: Your orignal uri starts with **/index.php/** . Try changing your rewrite destination to this **/index.php/allmodles?st=$1**

Comment: I have used this but i got same problem.

Comment: I guess there are more rules in the .htaccess file.

Comment: NO there have  1 rule but  when i am using ==>  RewriteRule ^allmodels/(.*)$ /allmodels?st=$1 [R,L]   It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

When i used following code that is working but above given code is not working.

```
   Options -Indexes
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```